# Compare elements iteratively

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, replacement

Assume I have the following data:

```
data = {{30, 8}, {37, 3}, {36, 8}, {40, 17}, {1, 4}}
```

and I need to apply the function EuclideanDistance between element 1 and 2, 2 and 3, and so on.

If the distance is more than a given number, I need to return a, and if not, b.

In pseudo-code, this could look something like this:

```
If[EuclideanDistance[p1,p2]>d, a, b]
```

So far, I have tried creating a pure function, referring to element 1 as #1 (or ##1), element 2 as #2 and so on, and then mapping, applying, and everything between.

However, as far as my understanding goes, this doesn't work because there is only 1 element in each application.

Also, this would give me problems when attempting to compare the last and first elements.

How can this be implemented?

Comment: You can use `MovingMap`.  In older versions, `Map` onto `Partition[list, 2, 1]` instead.

Comment: Or, you can use ``Developer`PartitionMap`` which combines `Map` and `Partition`. In v11, you can use `BlockMap` which does most of what ``Developer`PartitionMap`` does.

Comment: `If[(EuclideanDistance @@ #) > d, a, b] & /@
 Partition[data, 2, 1]`

Answer (score 11):

With [`BlockMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockMap.html):

```
res1 = BlockMap[Apply[EuclideanDistance], data, 2, 1]
```

With [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) and [`Partition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html):

```
res2 = EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[data, 2, 1]
```

---

With the `If` statement, one would get:

```
If[# > d, a, b] & /@ res
```

where `res` is either `res1` or `res2`.

An alternative to avoid the `If` could be:

```
{a, b}[[UnitStep[d - res] + 1]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Sometime `Differences` gives really good performance

```
If[# > 10, a, b] & /@ Norm /@ Differences@data
```

Or to avoid re-mapping:

```
If[Norm[#] > 10, a, b] & /@ Differences@data
```

Or to avoid re-mapping and still have a sequence of function application:

```
f[# > 10, a, b] &@*Norm /@ Differences@data
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `DistanceMatrix` and `UnitStep` (would need to be modified depending aim and strictness of inequality):

```
dm = DistanceMatrix[data]
f[x_, t_, a_, b_] := a + (b - a) UnitStep[x - t]
```

Visualizing:

```
Manipulate[
 With[{r = Map[f[#, t, 1, 2] &, N@dm, {2}]},
  Row[{
    Framed@
     TableForm[
      N@dm /. {x_?(# < t &) :> Style[x, Red], 
        x_?(# >= t &) :> Style[x, Blue]}, 
      TableHeadings -> {Range[5], Range[5]}],
    Framed@TableForm[r, TableHeadings -> {Range[5], Range[5]}], 
    ArrayPlot[r, ColorRules -> {1 -> Red, 2 -> Blue}]}]], {t, 1, 20, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1, No fair using animated graphics to make your case. :)